# retrieve data from a post request nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a super simple form

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
  PAGE
    <form method = "post" action="/login">
      pseudo: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
      mdp: <input type="password" name="password">
      <input type="submit" value="post">
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

and a server.js file:

```
 /******** Chargement des Middleware *********/
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 /******** Declaration des variables *********/

   /******** Configuration du serveur NodeJS - Port :  30002 *********/

const express = require('express');
const app = express(); // appel a expressJS
const server= app.listen(3116,function(){
 console.log('listening on port 3116');
});

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));

 /******** Gestion des URI ********/

  app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile('CERIGame/index.html',{ root:       __dirname });
   });

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  console.log("post received: %s %s", username,   password);
 });
```

i'm getting a "Cannot post /login" when i click on submit button and nothing in the console.
 any idea about what's wrong or missing please ?

Comment: Is that the exact error message?

Comment: yes, "cannot post /login"

Comment: Are you viewing the form at an HTTP(S) address served from your web server? If you're viewing it in `file://` mode, it might prevent `POST` since it wouldn't make sense in that context.

Comment: no it's an http address; i'm using the server of my university

Comment: I've never seen an error message that sparse before. Is there client-side JavaScript involved here that could be doing something other than a typical HTML form submit? Do you see anything in your web browser's development tools network tab that shows the details of the attempted post?

Comment: no no I already checked that, that's why i posted the problem  here cuz i don't see anything weird.

Comment: so what's the output in the network tab, does the post go through, are all the parameters there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on my machine and found everything working except one issue, you have to return the response from the `/login` API. Please find the code for returning response from server below.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  console.log("post received: %s %s", username,   password);
  return res.json({"success": 1})
 });
```

Just for your information when running on your local machine the web app should be at http://localhost:3116.